# UBUNTU 20.04.2 : Unable to run the scripts post installation as a late command

Tags: server, 20.04, scripts, usb-installation, user-data

I have been trying to run the script (`setup-proxy.sh`) using late-commands. I have tried various methods to make it run but unable to run the script. It fails with the **`exit status 1`**.

My late-commands section:

```
  late-commands:
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- touch /media/userkun.txt
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- echo "$(whoami)" >> /media/userkun.txt
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- cp /cdrom/setup-proxy.sh /media
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- cp /cdrom/setup-certs.sh /media
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod 777 /media/setup-proxy.sh
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod 777 /media/setup-certs.sh
  - sed -i 's/sudo//g' /target/media/setup-proxy.sh
  - sed -i 's/sudo//g' /target/media/setup-certs.sh
  - /target/media/setup-proxy.sh
```

I have also tried (*but no progress*) the last step of the late-commands section with:

```
curtin in-target --target=/target -- /bin/bash -c '/media/setup-proxy.sh'
curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash -c '/media/setup-proxy.sh'
curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash /media/setup-proxy.sh
```

The script `setup-proxy.sh` uses `sudo` calls for running the lines inside it. I thought error was due to the `sudo` calls and tried removing all instances of `sudo` in the `setup-proxy.sh` . But it was the same regardless. The scripts which I am copying does get copied to the `target` machine as mentioned **after installation**.

Kindly help. I am desperate to make this script run as a late-command at this point. Thank you for your time.

[The output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p5du.png)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
- cp /cdrom/script.sh /target/root/
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod +x /root/script.sh
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash /root/script.sh
```